# How to pass a date parameter into a Coinbase Fetch API call?

Tags: javascript, api

I am not able to get historical BTC spot price information using the Coinbase API.

Per their documentation, "You can also get historic prices with date parameter." https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2?shell#get-spot-price

I should be able to pass in a date parameter but when I do, I still get the real-time current price, not the historic price based on the date I input.

I've altered the date parameter formatting but it is still not recognizing it.

```
async function getBtcPrice(endpoint) {
const res = await fetch(endpoint);
const data = await res.json();

return data;
}

getBtcPrice('https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot')
.then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I am expecting to console.log the price on the date I input. Instead, only the current price is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

An example using `curl`, which you can translate for your javascript code is,

```
 curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot?date=2017-10-22
```

this returns,

```
{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"5930.41"}}
```

Note, that at the time of writing, the current price is given by,

```
curl https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot
```

returning

```
{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"8060.33"}}
```

showing a difference in the prices.